# Lazarus: How do I find detailed docs (class info) of objects?

Tags: class, object, properties, lazarus

Is there a way to find complete class info of an object in Lazarus. F1 doesn't work.

For example, I want to know the methods, events and properties of **TSQLQuery**. More specifically, I'm trying to find what constants I can use with the **state** property.

The docs I've found so far aren't really much help in this context.

I've also tried the menu that says 'object browser' but it simply points to the properites window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TSQLQuery and its unit sqldb is not documented.

The state property however is from the base tdataset ancestor of sqlquery, and that IS documented.

Try typing TDatasetstate or tdataset and press F1

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I found an easy way to find out at least the constants used. I am able to do it for every class... In the case of the TSQLQuery, I do this: I type the query object name DOT state. Then I see that it's of type TDatasetState. So I separately typed TDatasetState DOT. Now I see all the constants. This works for every class. And as a person new to the Lazarus platform, I find this pretty useful even without the Docs. Thanks for your directions. Also my help doesn't work but I guess that's a different issue.

Comment: It should be a matter of putting the CHMs in the appropriate directory. Recent (1.0.x) windows installers should do it by default.

Answer (score 0):

The best documentation is the source code. After you dropped a TSQLQuery on the form CTRL-click on the identifier "TSQLQuery" in the source editor. Lazarus will open the corresponding source file at the position where TSQLQuery is declared. Scroll down to the public methods or published properties to see everything you need. Identifiers usually are self-explanatory - the chm file often does not contain more info. And the source is always up-to-date.

You can do the same with any identifier. Depending on the Lazarus version you may land in the implementation part of the unit. In this case, just press SHIFT-CTRL Up/Down to go to the interface.